# Why does Windows 10 recommend a 1080p resolution when connecting to a 4k TV?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 4k-resolution, amd-graphics-card

I have a Thinkpad T495 connected to a 4K Samsung TV via HDMI and display settings set to 'extend these displays'. When I first connected the laptop, the TV's resolution was set to 1080p. I had to open up the display settings and manually change to 4k.

```
Edition Windows 10 Education
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎6/‎9/‎2020
OS build    19042.1110
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0
```

It works fine now, but I was wondering what factors go into Window's recommendation of the resolution

[Windows settings showing 1080p as the recommended resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrVXq.png)

Comment: Recommend because of the internal display in order to match resolutions and avoid additional calculations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the
[Lenovo Thinkpad T495](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-t-series/T495/p/22TP2TTT495),
there exist two versions of the laptop with the display adapter of:

- Integrated AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics
- Integrated AMD Radeon Vega 10 Graphics

According to the TechPowerUp website, the resolution limits for the
efficient functioning of the display adapters are:

- [AMD Radeon Vega 8](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-vega-8.c3042):
  1600x900 (it does badly at 1920x1080)
- [AMD Radeon RX Vega 10 Mobile](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-rx-vega-10-mobile.c3053):
  1600x900 (it does so-so with 1920x1080 and badly with more).

The display driver initially choose the best resolution that it
thought it could safely support with your hardware, as it cannot
know what you will be doing with it.

You are able to force the resolution to more than 1080p, but the
performance will not be optimal for some games and videos.